# Insert query with Select query

Tags: php

I want to select category id, category name, category type, average of rate columns in review table and i want to save it result table category id, category name, category type, average of rate in automatically. so i tried below code. but it didn't work. so if you have any solution please help me to fix this? or if have another method to accomplish my task can you please describe it. help me to fix this error to quickly.
I want to select category id, category name, category type, average of rate columns in review table and i want to save it result table category id, category name, category type, average of rate in automatically. so i tried below code. but it didn't work. so if you have any solution please help me to fix this? or if have another method to accomplish my task can you please describe it. help me to fix this error to quickly.

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("testing",$con);
function setReviews($con){
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $user_email=$_POST["user_email"];
        $user_name=$_POST["user_name"];
        $review=$_POST["review"];
        $rate=$_POST["rate"];
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT user_email FROM review WHERE user_email='$user_email'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql)>0) {
            echo "user mail already exist";
        }else{
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO review(user_email,user_name,rate,review) VALUES ('$user_email','$user_name','$rate','$review')");
        echo "submitted";
        }
    }
} 
function getratingsave($con){
    $category_id=1;
        $sql="INSERT INTO result (category_id,cat_name,cat_type,t_rate) SELECT category_id,AVG(rate),cat_name,cat_type FROM review WHERE category_id='$category_id'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
}
?>
```

Comment: In what way does this fail?  What's the actual error?  What is the result of the queries?  (Hint: You don't check the result or check for errors.  You should.  The database is *probably* telling you what's wrong.)

Comment: The mysql extension has been deprecated a while ago; you should use mysqli or pdo. And how to properly debug errors occurring when using those two, is something you can research yourself. Same as what you need to do against SQL injection.

Comment: Both the comments you already have here are very good advice.  Also check that you are calling these functions that you have declared.

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** Miss matched order of **column** and **values**

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO result (category_id,cat_name,cat_type,t_rate) SELECT category_id,AVG(rate),cat_name,cat_type FROM review WHERE category_id='$category_id'";
```

**Note :** Specified column order should be matched with value order.

To

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO result (category_id,cat_name,cat_type,t_rate) SELECT category_id,cat_name,cat_type,AVG(rate) FROM review WHERE category_id='$category_id'";
```

**2nd :** Mysql is deprecated try to use mysqli or PDO.

**3rd :** And also try to use prepared statement.

Comment: @NimeshaDharana: (1) None of us know what you tried.  (2) You still haven't told us any details about what "it not work" means.  Nobody here can see your screen or knows what's happening inside your computer.  You have to explain the problem.

Comment: I updated mine to this quarry..  
$sql="INSERT INTO result (category_id,cat_name,cat_type,t_rate) SELECT category_id,cat_name,cat_type,AVG(rate) FROM review WHERE category_id='$category_id'";